# Pyramid asterisk in PHP

Tags: php

Please see my code.

```
for ($row = $var; $row >= 1; --$row) {
            for($j=0;$j<$row;++$j)
            {echo "*";}
            echo "</br>";
            echo "&nbsp";
```

Output:

```
*****
 ****
 ***
 **
 *
```

But i need output as below:

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

Comment: duplicate the loop, inversed, with spaces, no <br>, right before the asterisks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out some of the string functions:

```
<?php

for ($i = 5; $i > 0; $i--) {
        echo str_repeat(' ', 5 - $i).str_repeat('*',$i).PHP_EOL;
}

for ($i = 5; $i > 0; $i--) {
        echo str_pad(str_repeat('*',$i),5,' ',STR_PAD_LEFT).PHP_EOL;
}
```

This runs on the command line, like so:

> php filename.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$var = 5;
echo "<div style='font-family:Courier New, Courier, monospace;'>";
for ($row = $var; $row >= 1; $row--) {

  for($i=$row;$i<$var;$i++)
  {
    echo "&nbsp";
  }

  for($j=0;$j<$row;$j++)
  {
    echo "*";
  }
  echo "<br>"; 
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: I added the `font-family:Courier New, Courier, monospace;` part to make sure that the width of each space is equal to the width of the asterisk