# Need code for specific pyramid in php

Tags: php

I have created like below:

```
$levels = 5;
$output = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $levels; $i = $i + 2) {
    $whitespace = ($levels - $i / 2 );
    $output[] = str_pad(' ', $whitespace, '-') . str_pad('', $i, '*');
}
echo implode("</br>", $output);
echo "\n";
echo "</br>";
echo implode("</br>", array_reverse($output));
//echo "\n";
echo "</br>";
```

```
---*
--***
-***** 
-*****
--***
---*
```

So, I need to hide or omit "-" from here.

```
   *
  ***
 ***** 
  ***
   *
```

Comment: `echo '* * ***** ******* ***** * *';`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Shomz Bit of a curve ball, wouldn't you agree? *lol* Someone posted an answer below, probably based on your comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Haha, call me Pied Piper 8)

Comment: Your question's unclear and you already posted something similar http://stackoverflow.com/q/36731505/ so I for one, was going to submit an answer based on what you posted, but have now decided not to.

Comment: @Shomz Heh heh, ok *"Pied Piper!"* ♫ oh and I decided to pass on it, based on ^^^

Comment: The *real* answer/solution is so simple, it's almost stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo it as:

```
<?php

echo "     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *";
```

Comment: Try it yourself and see what it outputs. It won't show a pyramid, it's going to echo it all in one line.

Comment: Oh sure, in HTML source it will, but not on screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nl2br()` to break the lines:

> Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

```
echo nl2br("
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *");
```

Comment: @Rakib Did this solve your problem? Maybe accept this answer by clicking on the tick mark below the upvote/ downvote buttons, thanks!